# How do I incrementally increase the output in a chart rendered by jQuery UI sliders?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-ui

I am looking for a way to dynamically update Highcharts based on the value determined by jQuery UI sliders. Let's say the price was $100 / month and 5 units a month were sold. Each month the data point would be calculated by the sum of the previous months, plus (unit*price) and the number of units would increase by 5 each month. For instance Month 1: (100*5) = 500 Month 2: 500 + (100*10) = 1500 Month 3: 1500 + (100*15) = 3000 Month 4: 3000 + (100*20) = 5000 etc... so the chart should look more like a curve. How can I go abouts doing this? Here is my jsFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/nlem33/eyGMu/2/

```
slide: function(event, ui) {
$('#slider2_value').html('$' + ui.value);
var newdata = [];
for (var i=0 ; i<6 ; i++) {
    newdata.push(ui.value * i);
}
chart.series[0].setData (newdata);
```

},

Comment: don't forget to accept if you'll find helpful answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you wanted? :-)

```
var sliderHandler = function (event, ui) {
    var newdata = [],
        data = [],
        sum = 0;

    if (this.id === 'slider1') {
        $('#slider1_value').html(ui.value);
        units = ui.value;
    } else {
        $('#slider2_value').html('$' + ui.value);
        price = ui.value;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        data.push(units * price);

        for (var j = 0; j < i; j++)
            sum += data[j];

        newdata.push(sum + units * price);
    }

    chart.series[0].setData(newdata);
    chart.series[1].setData(newdata);
}

$('#slider1').slider({

    min: min_value,
    max: max_value,
    step: 5,

    slide: sliderHandler,
    stop: function (event, ui) {

    }
});
```

Same for slider2

Here's your modified example with curve -> http://jsfiddle.net/eyGMu/5/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the time you spent on this I really appreciate it! :) It's very close to what I was looking for, the increments are right, however it seems that some of the starting values aren't calculating right. Whats happening is the chart is pulling the value from whichever slider that was updated last instead of calculating it from (slider1_value * slider2_value) heres an updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nlem33/eyGMu/4/